# Airodump-ng shows AP on negative channel

Tags: wireless, monitoring, aircrack-ng, airodump-ng

I am new to WiFi and was trying to learn pentesting with the aircrack-ng suite.

In the following airodump-ng excerpt, any idea why airodump-ng is showing an access point with negative value `-1` as the channel?

[image: airodump-ng excerpt displaying a negative channel value for one line]

The AP seems to be hidden but I got a reasonable PWR reading, as opposed to the ones with `PWR = -1` described in [Airodump-ng -1 DB networks](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/109362/airodump-ng-1-db-networks).

Intrigued by this behaviour, I tried to use Kismet and it actually shows a positive channel for that AP.

Using Airodump-ng with option `--channel` and using kismet found channel I got results. Still can't figure out what is going on

Comment: Does this answer you? https://forum.aircrack-ng.org/index.php?topic=1635.0 or this? https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/fix-channel-1-glitch-airodump-latest-kernel-0132161/

Comment: @schroeder thanks but dont think its my case I can actually see my monitoring interface hoppping betwen channels, my interface works fine, its airodump-ng that reports as channel -1 a channel that kismet using same interface find as lets say 4 or 11

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall airodump?

Comment: I'll give it a try